# How should a static database connection be initialised?

Tags: java, singleton, database-connection

This class is the only thing that should ever access the database and I'd like to give it a single connection object when my application starts up. However, instantiation may cause an exception to be thrown, so I can't do this:

```
public class DBManager {
    private static Connection conn = Database.getReadOnlyConnection();
    ...
    ...
}
```

I have a pretty ugly workaround, and I was wondering if there's a better way.

```
public class DBManager {
    private static Connection conn = null;
    private static DBManager instance = null;

    public static DBManager getInstance() throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {
        if (instance == null){
            instance = new DBManager();
        }
        return instance;
    }

    private DBManager() throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {
        conn = Database.getReadOnlyConnection();
    }

    ...
    ...
}
```

There's also this alternative:

```
public class DBManager {
    private static Connection conn = null;
    public static void setConnection(Connection conn) throws NotSupportedException{
        if (conn == null){
            this.conn = conn;
        }
        else {
            throw new NotSupportedException();
        }
    }
    ...
    ...
}
```

Is there a nicer way of handling this in Java?

**Update**

I've decided to use a static initializer block.

```
public class DBManager {
    private static Connection conn;
    static {
        try {
            conn = getReadOnlyConnection();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }
    ...
    ...
}
```

This causes the application to fail early if the database cannot be reached and avoids the problem of having to ensure that the DBManager is only being used via an instance.

Comment: Should your application be able to start up if you can't connect to the database?

Comment: What / why you define a particular solution  nice / ugly ?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis, if the application starts up and the database does not exist, it will be created by the Database class. There shouldn't be very many situations where a connection cannot be established. If the connection can't be established, then it doesn't matter if the application starts.

Comment: @gerrytan, if possible, I'd like to be able to use the DBManager without having to ensure that the getInstance or setConnection function has been called, in the same way you'd expect to be able to rely on default values for primitives.

Answer (score 0):

You program should be more robust - sure you may have a connection now, but what happens if the DB does down - use the same logic for `no DB now` as `DB goes down later`

Answer (score 0):

How about a static method and checking if the connection is still valid,

```
public class  Config{
private static Connection con;
private String dbUrl = "jdbc:mysql:/localhost:3306/dbname","username","password";

public static Connection getConnection() throws SQLException{

if(con== null){

con = DriverManager.getConnection(dbUrl);
}
if(!con.isValid(10)){
con = DriverManager.getConnection.getConnection(dbUrl);
}
return con;
}
}
```